# Google Maps Places autocomplete not returning specific address results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, location

## The problem

I am using Google Maps Javascript API, more specifically [Places autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

The autocomplete it's not returning any results when I try to find this place: "**W.W. Grainger Corporate Office**" (Place ID: ChIJS7FMg5WVD4gRyZBVa2677jg)

by this address: "**100 Grainger Pkwy, Lake Forest, IL 60045**"

I used to get the result by address, but now I no longer do.

Interestingly, it's not even showing on Google maps autocomplete. You have to press enter for results to show up.

## The workaround

I've changed the places address autocomplete for the [Places Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) but this way the users have to enter "W W Grainger" instead of the address "100 Grainger pkwy".

---

I tested writing the address full and abbreviated: "100 Grainger Parkway, Lake Forest", but got nothing. Also validated this address on Yahoo Maps to check it's existence.

Why is this happening? How come I used to get results before and not now?

I am considering removing the complete Google Places API dependency because of this edge case.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like that address is no longer in the geocoding database.

Comment: It works for me in Geocoder tool using autocomplete https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJS7FMg5WVD4gRyZBVa2677jg. Probably you caught the moment when Google was updating the data.